# OSQP failed to find solution for max sharpe ratio

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, constraint-programming, cvxpy

I have provided my code.  I have also provided the error it is throwing.  And I have provided sample data.  My actual data is too large to post but this gives you an idea of the data.  I am trying to use the pypfopt module to calculate the efficient frontier maximum sharpe ratio solution.  I'm using stock close price data for most of the s&p 500.  for a smaller sample of stocks like 150 it will find a solution, but for the larger samples it throws this error.  does anyone see what the issue might be?

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import datetime
import os
import matplotlib.style
from pandas.core.common import flatten
from functools import partial, reduce
import scipy.optimize as sco
import math


from pypfopt import EfficientFrontier
from pypfopt import risk_models
from pypfopt import expected_returns
from pypfopt.discrete_allocation import DiscreteAllocation, get_latest_prices    

# Calculate expected returns and sample covariance
mu = expected_returns.mean_historical_return(df)
S = risk_models.sample_cov(df)

# Optimise for maximal Sharpe ratio
ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S,verbose=True)
raw_weights = ef.max_sharpe()
```

error:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
           OSQP v0.6.0  -  Operator Splitting QP Solver
              (c) Bartolomeo Stellato,  Goran Banjac
        University of Oxford  -  Stanford University 2019
-----------------------------------------------------------------
problem:  variables n = 394, constraints m = 789
          nnz(P) + nnz(A) = 79388
settings: linear system solver = qdldl,
          eps_abs = 1.0e-05, eps_rel = 1.0e-05,
          eps_prim_inf = 1.0e-04, eps_dual_inf = 1.0e-04,
          rho = 1.00e-01 (adaptive),
          sigma = 1.00e-06, alpha = 1.60, max_iter = 10000
          check_termination: on (interval 25),
          scaling: on, scaled_termination: off
          warm start: on, polish: on, time_limit: off

iter   objective    pri res    dua res    rho        time
   1   0.0000e+00   1.00e+00   2.26e+03   1.00e-01   1.84e-02s
 200   8.0697e+01   2.87e+01   1.04e-01   5.08e-05   6.78e-02s
 400   1.1747e+02   4.23e+00   1.92e-02   5.08e-05   9.55e-02s
 600   9.8811e+01   2.63e+00   5.59e-04   5.08e-05   1.23e-01s
 800   9.4263e+01   2.06e+00   1.29e-03   5.08e-05   1.51e-01s
1000   9.0092e+01   1.62e+00   9.64e-04   5.08e-05   1.78e-01s
1200   8.6677e+01   1.43e+00   8.32e-04   5.08e-05   2.07e-01s
1400   8.3735e+01   1.33e+00   7.31e-04   5.08e-05   2.34e-01s
1600   8.1138e+01   1.24e+00   6.53e-04   5.08e-05   2.63e-01s
1800   7.8795e+01   1.16e+00   5.92e-04   5.08e-05   2.90e-01s
2000   7.6644e+01   1.09e+00   5.41e-04   5.08e-05   3.18e-01s
2200   7.4642e+01   1.03e+00   5.00e-04   5.08e-05   3.46e-01s
2400   7.2758e+01   9.76e-01   4.65e-04   5.08e-05   3.74e-01s
2600   7.0970e+01   9.32e-01   4.36e-04   5.08e-05   4.01e-01s
2800   6.9263e+01   8.93e-01   4.11e-04   5.08e-05   4.31e-01s
3000   6.7623e+01   8.59e-01   3.89e-04   5.08e-05   4.59e-01s
3200   6.6044e+01   8.40e-01   3.71e-04   5.08e-05   4.86e-01s
3400   6.4517e+01   8.36e-01   3.55e-04   5.08e-05   5.14e-01s
3600   6.3039e+01   8.30e-01   3.41e-04   5.08e-05   5.42e-01s
3800   6.1605e+01   8.24e-01   3.29e-04   5.08e-05   5.71e-01s
4000   6.0213e+01   8.17e-01   3.19e-04   5.08e-05   5.99e-01s
4200   5.8860e+01   8.09e-01   3.09e-04   5.08e-05   6.27e-01s
4400   5.7543e+01   8.01e-01   3.01e-04   5.08e-05   6.54e-01s
4600   5.6262e+01   7.92e-01   2.93e-04   5.08e-05   6.82e-01s
4800   5.5014e+01   7.83e-01   2.86e-04   5.08e-05   7.10e-01s
5000   5.3798e+01   7.74e-01   2.80e-04   5.08e-05   7.37e-01s
5200   5.2614e+01   7.65e-01   2.74e-04   5.08e-05   7.66e-01s
5400   5.1460e+01   7.56e-01   2.69e-04   5.08e-05   7.95e-01s
5600   5.0334e+01   7.46e-01   2.63e-04   5.08e-05   8.23e-01s
5800   4.9237e+01   7.37e-01   2.59e-04   5.08e-05   8.51e-01s
6000   4.8168e+01   7.28e-01   2.54e-04   5.08e-05   8.79e-01s
6200   4.7124e+01   7.18e-01   2.50e-04   5.08e-05   9.07e-01s
6400   4.6107e+01   7.09e-01   2.46e-04   5.08e-05   9.35e-01s
6600   4.5114e+01   7.00e-01   2.42e-04   5.08e-05   9.63e-01s
6800   4.4146e+01   6.91e-01   2.38e-04   5.08e-05   9.91e-01s
7000   4.3201e+01   6.82e-01   2.35e-04   5.08e-05   1.02e+00s
7200   4.2280e+01   6.73e-01   2.31e-04   5.08e-05   1.05e+00s
7400   4.1380e+01   6.64e-01   2.28e-04   5.08e-05   1.07e+00s
7600   4.0503e+01   6.55e-01   2.25e-04   5.08e-05   1.10e+00s
7800   3.9647e+01   6.46e-01   2.21e-04   5.08e-05   1.13e+00s
8000   3.8811e+01   6.37e-01   2.18e-04   5.08e-05   1.16e+00s
8200   3.7996e+01   6.29e-01   2.15e-04   5.08e-05   1.19e+00s
8400   3.7200e+01   6.20e-01   2.12e-04   5.08e-05   1.21e+00s
8600   3.6424e+01   6.12e-01   2.09e-04   5.08e-05   1.24e+00s
8800   3.5666e+01   6.04e-01   2.06e-04   5.08e-05   1.27e+00s
9000   3.4926e+01   5.96e-01   2.03e-04   5.08e-05   1.30e+00s
9200   3.4204e+01   5.88e-01   2.01e-04   5.08e-05   1.32e+00s
9400   3.3499e+01   5.80e-01   1.98e-04   5.08e-05   1.35e+00s
9600   3.2811e+01   5.72e-01   1.95e-04   5.08e-05   1.38e+00s
9800   3.2139e+01   5.64e-01   1.92e-04   5.08e-05   1.41e+00s
10000   3.1483e+01   5.57e-01   1.90e-04   5.08e-05   1.44e+00s

status:               maximum iterations reached
number of iterations: 10000
run time:             1.44e+00s
optimal rho estimate: 1.08e-04

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SolverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-c6bc50ed1e81> in <module>
      7 # Optimise for maximal Sharpe ratio
      8 ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S,verbose=True)
----> 9 raw_weights = ef.max_sharpe()
     10 # cleaned_weights = ef.clean_weights()

~/anaconda3/envs/pyopft/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypfopt/efficient_frontier.py in max_sharpe(self, risk_free_rate)
    224         ] + new_constraints
    225 
--> 226         self._solve_cvxpy_opt_problem()
    227         # Inverse-transform
    228         self.weights = (self._w.value / k.value).round(16) + 0.0

~/anaconda3/envs/pyopft/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pypfopt/base_optimizer.py in _solve_cvxpy_opt_problem(self)
    222                 opt.solve(solver=self._solver, verbose=self._verbose)
    223             else:
--> 224                 opt.solve(verbose=self._verbose)
    225         except (TypeError, cp.DCPError) as e:
    226             raise exceptions.OptimizationError from e

~/anaconda3/envs/pyopft/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py in solve(self, *args, **kwargs)
    394         else:
    395             solve_func = Problem._solve
--> 396         return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    397 
    398     @classmethod

~/anaconda3/envs/pyopft/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py in _solve(self, solver, warm_start, verbose, gp, qcp, requires_grad, enforce_dpp, **kwargs)
    752         solution = solving_chain.solve_via_data(
    753             self, data, warm_start, verbose, kwargs)
--> 754         self.unpack_results(solution, solving_chain, inverse_data)
    755         return self.value
    756 

~/anaconda3/envs/pyopft/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py in unpack_results(self, solution, chain, inverse_data)
   1066             raise error.SolverError(
   1067                     "Solver '%s' failed. " % chain.solver.name() +
-> 1068                     "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
   1069                     "information.")
   1070         self.unpack(solution)

SolverError: Solver 'OSQP' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
```

data:

```
print(df)

             MMM         ABT        ABBV       ATVI        AMD         AAP  \
0     175.869995  107.610001  103.809998  76.190002  86.769997  150.009995   
1     175.714996  107.355003  103.889999  76.690002  87.209999  149.005005   
2     176.135696  107.330002  104.010002  76.870003  87.220001  148.613098   
3     175.979996  107.415001  104.080002  77.010002  87.070000  148.529999   
4     176.350006  107.500000  103.849998  76.900002  87.550003  148.865005   
...          ...         ...         ...        ...        ...         ...   
1563  174.399994  108.360001  102.957497  90.779999  91.559998  160.789993   
1564  174.679993  108.379997  103.140800  90.959999  91.645897  160.770004   
1565  174.509995  108.349998  103.129997  90.919998  91.694901  160.904999   
1566  174.520004  108.339996  103.309998  90.910004  91.800003  160.690002   
1567  174.520004  108.349998  103.260002  90.959999  91.809998  160.679993   

            AES        AFL           A        AKAM  ...        WMB  \
0     21.125000  45.455002  115.970001  102.639999  ...  21.580000   
1     21.004999  45.139999  116.779999  102.930000  ...  21.510000   
2     21.000000  45.209999  116.639999  102.722504  ...  21.559999   
3     21.020000  45.209999  116.394997  102.750000  ...  21.610001   
4     21.075001  45.200001  116.230003  103.400398  ...  21.590000   
...         ...        ...         ...         ...  ...        ...   
1563  23.170000  43.840000  117.589996  107.214996  ...  20.684999   
1564  23.190001  43.830002  117.410004  107.349998  ...  20.730000   
1565  23.270000  43.775002  117.349998  107.370003  ...  20.760000   
1566  23.270000  43.840000  117.309998  107.430000  ...  20.750000   
1567  23.270000  43.840000  117.309998  107.459999  ...  20.740000   

            WYNN        XEL        XRX        XLNX         XYL         YUM  \
0     100.320000  68.540001  23.430000  135.860001   96.665001  106.864998   
1      99.935997  68.430000  23.389999  136.429993   96.440002  106.300003   
2     100.199997  68.410004  23.420000  136.449997   96.254997  106.400002   
3     100.459999  68.500000  23.320000  136.050003   96.559998  106.385002   
4      99.745003  68.580002  23.299999  136.850006   96.449997  106.349998   
...          ...        ...        ...         ...         ...         ...   
1563  113.654999  64.550003  22.610001  141.589996  100.099998  107.500000   
1564  113.879997  64.599998  22.629999  141.699997  100.150002  107.589996   
1565  114.150002  64.620003  22.600000  141.789993  100.230003  107.669998   
1566  114.330002  64.680000  22.580000  141.990005  100.139999  107.550003   
1567  114.389999  64.629997  22.580000  141.990005  100.250000  107.540001   

             ZBH       ZION         ZTS  
0     149.675003  40.619999  161.639999  
1     149.350006  40.860001  160.850006  
2     148.925003  40.750000  161.169998  
3     149.240005  40.669998  161.000000  
4     149.770004  40.430000  160.979996  
...          ...        ...         ...  
1563  149.490005  43.174999  160.645004  
1564  149.604996  43.285000  160.740005  
1565  149.500000  43.360001  160.643204  
1566  149.250000  43.330002  160.774994  
1567  149.250000  43.340000  160.720001  

[1568 rows x 393 columns]
```

Comment: OSQP needs more iterations. This can be specified in CVXPY, but I am not sure how to do this through pypfopt.

Comment: You can also try another optimizer as suggested. Given my origin I would recommend Mosek.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK ok thank you both for getting back to me so quickly.  I tried looking for the parameter to increase the max_iter in pypfopt, not having much luck.  I'll try changing the optimizer.  if I switch to Mosek will I need to reformulate the problem?

Comment: No. Cvx does that.

Comment: @ErlingMOSEK are you familiar with how select a different optimizer in pypfopt?  I've been looking through the documentation on baseOptimizer class but it's not clear.  an example line of code would be great.

Comment: I have not used pypfopt. Sorry.